# How get the list of frames or text present under RecyclerView?

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium

How get the list of frames or text present under RecyclerView.

Always list of webelements returns `null`. Using `Appium` with `UI AutomatorViewer` for viewing `android` app `xpath`.

I have tried below code, but it didn't work for me.

```
WebElement plist = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[contains(@resources-id,'id/patient_list_view') and @index='6']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around as mentioned below,

```
  List<WebElement> alltheListfromView=driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@resources-id,'id/patient_list_view']"); 
//Add if any other elements attributes are available

for (WebElement elements: alltheListfromView) {
    System.out.println(webElement.getText());

}
```